# spree only show products in current taxon not current taxon and descendants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

When on taxon page like /clothing how can I change it to only show products in clothing not clothing and its subcategories? In the taxons_controller.rb it is calling

```
@searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(:taxon => @taxon.id))
@products = @searcher.retrieve_products
```

In retrieve_products https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/85da083faf81a4b0150e183d2f7aec988e674b07/core/lib/spree/core/search/base.rb#L15 it is using

```
get_base_scope
```

which in turn is using:

```
base_scope.in_taxon(taxon) unless taxon.blank?
```

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/b66ea0229646062acb7b6f89ac2447f5ffc862fb/core/app/models/spree/product/scopes.rb#L78 even says in the scope that it includes descendants. How do I override this to only show products in current category?

Answer (score 2):

Found I had to override the search scope in the model. For reference if anyone finds this:

```
    module Spree
      Product.class_eval do
        add_search_scope :in_taxon do |taxon|
          Spree::Product.joins(:taxons).where(Taxon.table_name => { :id => taxon.id }).
          order("spree_products_taxons.position ASC")
        end
      end
    end
```